# Projecting a point on a plane through a matrix

Tags: matrices, projective-geometry

I need to render some shadows in opengl, one way to do this is to render your object twice, a first time multiplying it by a special "shadow matrix" that flat your object on a plane generating the shadow and a second time for the object itself.

To create the shadow matrix, a 4x4 matrix in an 16-array by rows, I pass the plane, on which the shadow is going to lie, and the light position.

I created a little program in Java to test it, but its not working. I checked the passages tens of times, but I didnt find anything, so I guess it is a logic error

```
public class test {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 2;
    int w = 3;
    float floor[][] = {
        {-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f},
        {1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f},
        {1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},
        {-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}};
    private float shadow_floor[] = new float[16];
    float light_position[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f};

    public test() {
        //Find floorplane based on thre known points
        float plane_floor[] = calculatePlane(floor[1], floor[2], floor[3]);

        //store shadowMatrix for floor
        shadow_floor = shadowMatrix(plane_floor, light_position);

        float[] point = new float[]{1.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f, 1.0f};

        float[] projectedPoint = pointFmatrixF(point, shadow_floor);

        System.out.println("plane: (" + plane_floor[x] + ", " + plane_floor[y] + ", "
                + plane_floor[z] + "," + plane_floor[w]);
        System.out.println("point: (" + point[x] + ", " + point[y] + ", " + point[z] + ", "
                + point[w] + ")");
        System.out.println("projectedPoint: (" + projectedPoint[x] + ", " + projectedPoint[y]
                + ", " + projectedPoint[z] + ", " + projectedPoint[w] + ")");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        test test = new test();
    }

    // make shadow matrix
    public float[] shadowMatrix(float plane[], float light_pos[]) {
        float shadow_mat[] = new float[16];
        float dot;


        dot = plane[x] * light_pos[x] + plane[y] * light_pos[y]
                + plane[z] * light_pos[z] + plane[w] * light_pos[w];

        shadow_mat[0] = dot - light_pos[x] * plane[x];
        shadow_mat[4] = -light_pos[x] * plane[y];
        shadow_mat[8] = -light_pos[x] * plane[z];
        shadow_mat[12] = -light_pos[x] * plane[3];

        shadow_mat[1] = -light_pos[y] * plane[x];
        shadow_mat[5] = dot - light_pos[y] * plane[y];
        shadow_mat[9] = -light_pos[y] * plane[z];
        shadow_mat[13] = -light_pos[y] * plane[w];

        shadow_mat[2] = -light_pos[z] * plane[x];
        shadow_mat[6] = -light_pos[z] * plane[y];
        shadow_mat[10] = dot - light_pos[z] * plane[z];
        shadow_mat[14] = -light_pos[z] * plane[w];

        shadow_mat[3] = -light_pos[w] * plane[x];
        shadow_mat[7] = -light_pos[w] * plane[y];
        shadow_mat[11] = -light_pos[w] * plane[z];
        shadow_mat[15] = dot - light_pos[w] * plane[w];

        return shadow_mat;
    }

    public float[] calculatePlane(float p1[], float p2[], float p3[]) {
        //Array for planlikningen
        float plane[] = new float[4];

        //Gitt to vektorer (tre punkter) i planet kan normalen regnes ut
        //Vi vil ha aboluttverdier
        plane[x] = (((p2[y] - p1[y]) * (p3[z] - p1[z])) - ((p2[z] - p1[z])
                * (p3[y] - p1[y])));
        plane[y] = (((p2[z] - p1[z]) * (p3[x] - p1[x])) - ((p2[x] - p1[x])
                * (p3[z] - p1[z])));
        plane[z] = (((p2[x] - p1[x]) * (p3[y] - p1[y])) - ((p2[y] - p1[y])
                * (p3[x] - p1[x])));
        plane[w] = -(plane[x] * p1[x] + plane[y] * p1[y] + plane[z] * p1[z]);


        return plane;
    }

    public float[] pointFmatrixF(float[] point, float[] matrix) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 1;
        int z = 2;
        float[] transformedPoint = new float[4];

        transformedPoint[x] =
                matrix[0] * point[x]
                + matrix[4] * point[y]
                + matrix[8] * point[z]
                + matrix[12];
        transformedPoint[y] =
                matrix[1] * point[x]
                + matrix[5] * point[y]
                + matrix[9] * point[z]
                + matrix[13];
        transformedPoint[z] =
                matrix[2] * point[x]
                + matrix[6] * point[y]
                + matrix[10] * point[z]
                + matrix[14];
        transformedPoint[w] = 1;

        return transformedPoint;
    }
}
```

If my light is on (0, 0, 10) and an hypotetic point P1 (that could be a vertex of a triangle) is in (1, 0, 5) then the projection of P1 on the xy plane should be (2, 0, 0), but it is not..

This is the current output

```
plane: (0.0, -0.0, 4.0,-0.0
point: (1.0, 0.0, 5.0, 1.0)
projectedPoint: (40.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Much theory up front, the actual bug fixing is way down there. The theory covers the general approach of how you come up with such a projection matrix and servers as a general answer to this kind of question, while the bug fixing is pretty local and specific to your implementation.

## Theory

### The line

Suppose you have the (variable) coordinates of your input point $P$, and the (fixed) coordinates of your light source $L$. Then any point on the line between these two points can be expressed as a linear combination $\lambda P + \mu L$. And conversely any linear combination will represent a point on that line. So for the projected point $P'$ you get the condition $$P'=\lambda P+\mu L$$

### The plane

Let $F\cdot Q$ represent the dot product between the coordinates of your plane $F$ and the coordinates of a point $Q$. A point $Q$ lies on that plane if and only if $F\cdot Q=0$. So for the projected point $P'$ you get the condition $$F\cdot P'=0$$

### The intersection

Now you have to combine these two: find coefficients $\lambda$ and $\mu$ such that the second equation holds. There is a very elegant way to do this, known (to some) as Plücker's $\mu$.

\begin{align*}
\lambda &= F\cdot L \\
\mu &= -F\cdot P \\
P' &= (F\cdot L)P - (F\cdot P)L
\end{align*}

The point chosen in this fashion will automatically lie on the plane, therefore will be your desired projected point.

### As a matrix

Now you simply have to split that definition into its individual components.

\begin{align*}
P'_i &= \sum_{j=1}^4 F_jL_jP_i - \sum_{j=1}^4 F_jP_jL_i &
\forall i&\in\{1,2,3,4\} \\
M_{ij} &= -F_jL_i + \begin{cases}
F\cdot L &\text{if }i=j \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} &
\forall i,j&\in\{1,2,3,4\} \\
M &= \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda-F_1L_1 & -F_2L_1 & -F_3L_1 & -F_4L_1 \\
-F_1L_2 & \lambda-F_2L_2 & -F_3L_2 & -F_4L_2 \\
-F_1L_3 & -F_2L_3 & \lambda-F_3L_3 & -F_4L_3 \\
-F_1L_4 & -F_2L_4 & -F_3L_4 & \lambda-F_4L_4
\end{pmatrix}
& \text{with }\lambda&=F\cdot L
\end{align*}

## Your code

So your matrix does look reasonable. Your `dot` corresponds to my $\lambda$, and all the rest looks sane as well. Your problem lies with the `pointFmatrixF` method. There you incorrectly assume that the last coordinate of the resulting point will be `1`. In this case it will be `40`, so after fixing that line you get `projectedPoint: (40.0, 0.0, 0.0, 40.0)` which is just another homogenous representantion of the point `(1, 0, 0)`. Simply divide all other coordinates by the last coordinate.

Also notice that your `pointFmatrixF` does implicitely assume `point[w] == 1`. This is the case for your special input, but not true in general. So you probably should multiply by the fourth component as well.

Your question claims a light source at `(0, 0, 10)` which would be homogenized to `(0, 0, 10, 1)`. Your code however has a light at `(0, 0, 10, 0)`, which is a light infinitely far away in the `z` direction. Fixing that as well, you get `projectedPoint: (40.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0)` which is the `(2, 0, 0)` you expected.

Comment: Huge answer, thanks for the deep and exhaustive explanation, I did not +1 just because I can't for the moment (I need 15 reputation). Thanks a lot MvG ;)